# keyboard settings on ubuntu 18.04 LTS - my PC style keyboard switches to Mac style keyboard randomly

Tags: 18.04, keyboard-layout

My keyboard is now behaving like an apple mac. For instance when I press the '#' key I get a '\', and '@' and '"' keys are the "wrong" way round - i.e. behaves like a Mac. I have worked out how to change it back to the GB keyboard layout bindings. I type `setxkbmap gb` in the terminal.

My problem is that the keyboard behaviour seems to randomly change. I will continue to monitor to try to work out what is causing the problem but every now and again I get "/////" appearing when I type "######".

I'd like to stop the keyboard binding changing if possible.

Background:

I have a linux laptop from made by EntroWare with a GB keyboard layout. Picture here:

[GB keyboard layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJ1cB.png)

Prior to the problem, I performed a reset of my ubuntu settings using `deconf reset -f /`. I don't know if this caused a problem or was coincidental.

My keyboard configuration file is as follows, and I can't see anything obviously wrong with it:

```
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="gb"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS=""

BACKSPACE="guess"
```

Comment: Hi alexxcollins, what you can do is answer your own question, that way if someone is looking for an answer to the same or similar question they can see at a glance that your question as been resolved. You can also use the green checkmark to make it the accepted answer. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much @Robby1212. It turns out I haven't quite solved the problem. My keyboard bindings just changed back to MacOS style bindings. It's less of a problem now as fixing in the terminal is so easy. But it's still weird, so I'm going to leave the modified question open to see if anyone has any idea.